# Meteor get username in a publish function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

i want to publish a collection in Meteor with a find param and the param is,
 that it searches in the collection after the name of the user

I am using the Meteor accounts-password package and i maked sure the username is inserted in the Users collection but it does not work ;(

```
Meteor.publish("einladungen", function() {
      return Events.find({ Eingeladen: Meteor.user().username }); 
  })
```

I am searching in the Events collection a field in an array

the name of the Array is "Eingeladen" and when i put after the ": " the name "Hanna" then i get only the events where Hanna is find in the array so this is working fine but it only works for "Hanna" and not for the rest of the users

I appreciate every help ;)  Thanks

Comment: [`Meteor.user()`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-user) is not defined in publish functions. You can use [`this.userId`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Subscription-userId) in publish functions instead.

Comment: when i use this than i only get the id but i want the username

Comment: So you need to fetch the username from the database (as the answers already suggested) and use that after. Or pass the username as parameter to the function.

Comment: Also slightly off-topic: it's a bad idea to use the username as an identifier - you would need to disallow duplicates and changes to it. The userId is unique and better suited for tasks like these.

Comment: yes you are right but for me it will do fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Meteor.publish("einladungen", function() {
    const username = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId).username;
    return Events.find({ Eingeladen: username }); 
})
```